# Catch timeupdate event of an audio tag in vaadin

Tags: java, html, audio, vaadin

I use the audio tag in a component as propsed here: https://cookbook.vaadin.com/embed-audio

Now I want to fire an event when the audio plays. I found out that the audio tag provides the *timeupdate* event. I can catch it and it workes well. But now I want to get the current time of the audio playing. I read that the audio element has an attribute *currentTime*. But when I want to get that attribute from the audio element, it is not existing.

I printed all attributes of audio and everyting a get is *src* and *style*. Hope you can point me in the right direction here, since this does absolutely not make sense to me.

Edit: When I query the attribute via executeJs like:

```
UI.getCurrent().getPage().executeJs("return $0.currentTime", audio.getElement());
```

... , I get the value I'm looking for but then, the event listener does not work synchrnously anymore.

My class looks like that:

```
@Tag("audio")
public class Audio extends Component implements HasSize {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static final PropertyDescriptor<String, String> srcDescriptor = PropertyDescriptors
            .attributeWithDefault("src", "");

    public Audio() {
        super();
        getElement().setProperty("controls", true);
    }

    public Audio(String src) {
        setSrc(src);
        getElement().setProperty("controls", true);
    }

    public String getSrc() {
        return get(srcDescriptor);
    }

    public void setSrc(String src) {
        set(srcDescriptor, src);
    }

    public void setSrc(final AbstractStreamResource resource) {
        getElement().setAttribute("src", resource);
    }

    public void play() {
        getElement().callJsFunction("play");
    }

    public void stop() {
        getElement().callJsFunction("stop");
    }

    @DomEvent("timeupdate")
    public static class TimeUpdateEvent extends ComponentEvent<Audio> {

        private final int progress;

        public TimeUpdateEvent(Audio audio, boolean fromClient) {
            super(audio, fromClient);
            String currentTime = audio.getElement().getAttribute("currentTime");
            this.progress = Integer.valueOf(currentTime);
        }

        public Audio getAudio() {
            return (Audio) this.source;
        }

        public int getProgress() {
            return this.progress;
        }
    }

    public Registration addTimeUpdateListener(ComponentEventListener<Audio.TimeUpdateEvent> listener) {
        return addListener(Audio.TimeUpdateEvent.class, listener);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/71044894/8962195

Comment: Thanks, that looks good. Unfortunately, in my case the event I get is empty (a "generic event" as described here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/timeupdate_event). So I need to access the element to see the chaning data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found a way using property chance listeners. I'm observice the javascript property *currentTime* and react to the *timeupdate* event. This does not emit a *ComponentEvent* but I can live with that.

```
public Audio() {
    super();
    this.getElement().addPropertyChangeListener("currentTime", "timeupdate", e -> {
        currentTime = Float.parseFloat(e.getValue().toString());
    });
    getElement().setProperty("controls", true);
}
```